# Assert failed: std::move(hal_2_1_verifier).Run(). Initialize, LE Audio Client requires Bluetooth Audio HAL V2.1 at least

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I recently got a new Macbook Pro and am trying to set up Android Studio. I've installed Java 8, Dart, Flutter, and Android Studio and when I tried running the base code that it gives you when you create a new project, I get a repeat of this in the terminal:

```
F/bt_stack(20411): [FATAL:client.cc(3938)] Assert failed: std::move(hal_2_1_verifier).Run(). Initialize, LE Audio Client requires Bluetooth Audio HAL V2.1 at least. Either disable LE Audio Profile, or update your HAL
F/bt_stack(20411): #00 0x00000070b5806113 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bbb113
F/bt_stack(20411): #01 0x00000070b50889fb /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x000000000043d9fb
F/bt_stack(20411): #02 0x00000070b5137307 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x00000000004ec307
F/bt_stack(20411): #03 0x00000070b580ec37 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc3c37
F/bt_stack(20411): #04 0x00000070b580df3f /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc2f3f
F/bt_stack(20411): #05 0x00000070b580e303 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc3303
F/bt_stack(20411): #06 0x00000070b581134f /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc634f
F/bt_stack(20411): #07 0x00000070b5838783 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bed783
F/bt_stack(20411): #08 0x00000070b52bd483 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000672483
F/bt_stack(20411): #09 0x00000070b52bce97 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000671e97
F/bt_stack(20411): #10 0x00000070b52bd9b7 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x00000000006729b7
F/bt_stack(20411): #11 0x00000073d242f3b3 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so+0x00000000000b63b3
F/bt_stack(20411): #12 0x00000073d23cc0bb /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so+0x00000000000530bb
F/bt_stack(20411):
```

There's no actual errors when I navigate through my Android Emulator but I wanted to know how to fix this so it doesn't do that.

Comment: This seems to be a flutter error instead of your code error. There's already an issue opened at flutter github repository about this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/129480

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue in Android Emulator 33.1.13 on Macbook with M chips:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288717403

Looks like you can't be fixed by users and we just need to wait until Google fix it. You could voute for this issur on Google issuetracker, it may help to fix it with bigger priority.

Answer (score 7):

As anber wrote - this issue for M chips. Workaround - disable bluetooth over ADB:

```
adb shell cmd bluetooth_manager disable
```