# Android emulator bluetooth on off frequently

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

Hello I'm using Apple M2 MacBook with ventura 13.4.
When I run emulator on my Android studio it continuously switching bluetooth on and off.

Like this

[image]

as well as in debug console show as following. Repeating following debug message.

```
F/bt_stack(26098): 
F/bt_stack(26177): [FATAL:client.cc(3938)] Assert failed: std::move(hal_2_1_verifier).Run(). Initialize, LE Audio Client requires Bluetooth Audio HAL V2.1 at least. Either disable LE Audio Profile, or update your HAL
F/bt_stack(26177): #00 0x0000007c79e0e113 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bbb113
F/bt_stack(26177): #01 0x0000007c796909fb /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x000000000043d9fb
F/bt_stack(26177): #02 0x0000007c7973f307 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x00000000004ec307
F/bt_stack(26177): #03 0x0000007c79e16c37 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc3c37
F/bt_stack(26177): #04 0x0000007c79e15f3f /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc2f3f
F/bt_stack(26177): #05 0x0000007c79e16303 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc3303
F/bt_stack(26177): #06 0x0000007c79e1934f /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bc634f
F/bt_stack(26177): #07 0x0000007c79e40783 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000bed783
F/bt_stack(26177): #08 0x0000007c798c5483 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000672483
F/bt_stack(26177): #09 0x0000007c798c4e97 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x0000000000671e97
F/bt_stack(26177): #10 0x0000007c798c59b7 /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so+0x00000000006729b7
F/bt_stack(26177): #11 0x0000007f89aeb3b3 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so+0x00000000000b63b3
F/bt_stack(26177): #12 0x0000007f89a880bb /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so+0x00000000000530bb
F/bt_stack(26177):
```

It is worked on **wipe data** on emulator.I tried creating new emulators also.
But first time it worked well and after it raised previous error again.

If anything not clear or want more information please leave a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Am facing same issue with M2 mac book

Comment: @IlyasArafath did you find any solution for that. Clearing androd emulator cache solved problem for temporary.

Comment: Hasanda I tried with wipe data but it is not working, are you using mac with M chip

Comment: @IlyasArafath Yes, M2 one

Comment: Its totally crap, have the same thing. No solution

Comment: I was using Trimasu System image on the emulator,So I Updated Android studio to latest and then selected API 34 system image, now it is working fine. @KasunHasanga

Answer (score 0):

This issue is yet to be fixed by google but you can disable the bluetooth by running the following command on your terminal
`adb shell cmd bluetooth_manager disable` as suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592458/14600303)